# Generate Excel file with PhpSpreadsheet in Codeigniter from a view

Tags: codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to generate an Excel file with CodeIgniter and the PhpSpreadsheet library from a view. The reports that I need to make are not a list but much more complex and I can generate them more quickly with a view and sending parameters. This is my code:

```
$data = $this->model->bringdata();
$view = $this->load->view("data_view", $ data);
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
$writer-> save($view);
```

And the following error is shown

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen (): Filename can not be empty
>
> Filename: Writer / Html.php
>
> Line Number: 160

In the PhpSpreadsheet documentation it shows that an html page must be explicitly sent:

> $writer->save("05featuredemo.htm");

Is there any way to do what I need?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple solution, you need to pass true to the third argument of load->view in order for it to return a string rather than sending it to the browser.

```
$view = $this->load->view("data_view", $ data, true);
```

**Added after comment**

I made the mistake of not looking into how the Html writer works.

The HTML writer writes a spreadsheet as an html file. It does not create a spreadsheet. As I understand it (and I might be mistaken) you can use `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html` to read an html file into a spreadsheet.

In your case I think you will have to save the string returned from `$this->load->view()` to a temporary file. CodeIgniter's file_helper might be useful here.

You then read the temporary file to create a spreadsheet. After that you can use `$writer` to save the spreadsheet somewhere as any of the file types the PhpSpreadsheet supports.

```
$view = $this->load->view("data_view", $data, true);

$this->load->helper("file");
$fileName = "temp_file_name.html";
$path = "full/path/to/some_writable_folder/";
$path_file = $path . $fileName; 

if (write_file($path_file, $view))
{
    //create spreadsheet the temp html
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($path_file);

    //write out to html file
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($path."05featuredemo.htm");

    //delete the temporary file
    unlink($path_file);
}
else
{
    //handle the failure to write the temp file
}
```

I haven't tested this and I'm not sure you really want to save to an html file, but I think the above is close to the answer.

**Second addition**

If you want to save .xlsx files you need an `Xlsx` writer. Use the following instead of what's shown above.

```
//write out to excel file
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($ path. "doc.xlsx");
```

I confess that I have never used, or considered using the `html` reader so I'm not sure you'll get what you want. I honestly think that creating an html table so you can import it into excel is probably doing it the hard way.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DFriend, but now I am presented with the following error:


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(<h3>Text H3</h3> ...): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
Filename: Writer/Html.php
Line Number: 160
Backtrace:File: C:\wamp64\www\servidor\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html.php
Line: 160
Function: fopen
File: C:\wamp64\www\servidor\application\controllers\Prueba.php
Line: 37
Function: save
File: C:\wamp64\www\servidor\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: See the addition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again @DFriend, but I have a doubt in this line:
$ writer->save ($path. "05featuredemo.htm");
The correct way would be?
$ writer->save ($ path. "doc.xlsx");

I made that change and the doc.xlsx file is empty and when I try to open a message that says "Invalid file format" is displayed

Comment: Thank you again and again @DFriend. I did not noticed it. It worked for me correctly. Now I start to investigate how the styles are placed in the cells and my work will be full.

Comment: The reports that I need to present are very complicated and parametrizable. For me it is easier to generate a view in CodeIgniter and that transforms it into an Excel or PDF file if the user wants it.